# scatter plot Highlighted points using Core-plot in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot, scatter-plot

My code is below:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
      [self generateDataSamples];

    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingview=[[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]   initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:hostingview];

    graph=[[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    hostingview.hostedGraph =graph;

    // Border
    graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.cornerRadius = 0.0f;

    // Paddings
    graph.paddingLeft = 0.0f;
    graph.paddingRight = 0.0f;
    graph.paddingTop = 0.0f;
    graph.paddingBottom = 0.0f;

    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 70.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 20.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 20.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 80.0;


    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(7.0)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(50.0)];


    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1.0");
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0.0");
    x.minorTicksPerInterval =9;
   // x.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
   // x.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;

    x.title = @"X Axis";
    x.titleOffset = 30.0;
    x.titleLocation = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1.25");

    // Label y with an automatic label policy. 
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0.0");
    y.minorTicksPerInterval =9;
    y.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 8;
    //y.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
    // y.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
    y.labelOffset = 10.0;

    y.title = @"Y Axis";
    y.titleOffset = 30.0;
    y.titleLocation = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1.0");

    // Set axes
    graph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, nil];



    CPTScatterPlot *datasourceLinePlot =[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    datasourceLinePlot.dataSource =self;

    [graph addPlot:datasourceLinePlot];

    [datasourceLinePlot release];
    [graph release];
    [hostingview release];

}
```

This code generate Scatter-plot using Core-plot library in iphone ...!

Code is Working Perfectly below output.

[image]

but i am try highlight points no idea....!

I want Highlight x and y value points like dot....!

Help Me with us...!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a plot symbol and add this to your line plot.

**Objective-C**

```
CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
plotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];
plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0);
datasourceLinePlot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol;
```

**Swift**

```
let plotSymbol = CPTPlotSymbol.ellipse()
plotSymbol.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.white())
plotSymbol.size = CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)
datasourceLinePlot.plotSymbol = plotSymbol
```